# How to change the format of Excel in VSTO Project?

Tags: vsto

We have a VSTO project for Excel and the current excel document that is binded is .XLSX format, now we want to convert the .XLSX to .XLSB (binary), is there a easy way to do it or we have to create a new project from scratch and keep adding all modules and files manually? Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new project. If you unlink the VSTO solution from the existing workbook then it could be saved to the other file format and used as the basis for the new project. And you can copy the code in the existing project over to the code files created for the new project - no need to retype everything.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, that is what we are doing now, i wish if there is a more easier way like converting the format :(